# Xwin -query IPaddr opens blank screen for CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, cygwin, x11, centos6

Actually, I am trying to connect to a remote Linux CentOS machine through Cygwin by the following command:

```
xwin -query IPaddr
```

Output: a blank display was shown.

Note:
If I try to login through:  `ssh -Y user@IPaddr` , I am able to open the graphical applications.

I am able to connect and interact with other linux machine through GUI.

I tried different solutions like `xhost +` , but nothing helped.

Os: CentOS 
My machine: Windows 7

Comment: Are you trying to run remote X applications on your local X display? Or are you trying to run a remote X server on your local X display?

Comment: I think, I am trying to run a remote X server on local X display. I am a newbie to X. Actually, I am trying to access the Linux(CentOS) machine similar to Remote desktop in windows.

Comment: If you want to run a desktop environment/window manager on the remote machine then yes, that's right. Have you used X locally on that machine before? Does it have a graphical login screen?

Comment: Yeah Etan, I have used X locally on that machine and it has graphical login screen.

Comment: Then, assuming things are set up correctly, you should see that login screen when your XDMCP query connects to that remote machine. Perhaps it isn't set up correctly on that end for this? (I haven't set up XDMCP in ages so I don't really recall any details unfortunately.)